# Running sum maximum item minimization

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, theory

I am making a physics optimizer, where a critical part is solved by the following CS question.

You are given an array of random signed integers. Their sum is zero. One can make a loop that keeps a running sum as follows:

```
int running_sum = 0;
int sum_peak = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++ )
{
  running_sum += int_array[i];
  sum_peak = max( sum_peak, abs( running_sum ) );
}

assert( running_sum == 0 );
```

The task is to minimize the resultant sum_peak by permuting the initial int_array. My thoughts so far: the naive approach takes an exponential amount of time to run. This problem does not seem to be expressed by any NP-C problems I know of. I can't think of any way to represent this problem as a graph problem.

If X is the largest number (by absolute value) in the array, the upper and lower bounds of max_sum are N and N/2, respectively.

EDIT: examples.

{-4, -6, 10}: reorder the list as the following: {-6, 10, -4}, so that the sum_peak is -6.

{1, 1, 1, 1, -4}: reorder the list as the following: { 1, 1, -4, 1, 1 }, so that the sum_peak is +2.

Comment: "The task is to minimize max_sum." Please clarify this.

Comment: Do you mean by reordering the integers?

Comment: Yes. Should be fixed now.

Comment: How good do you need the solution to be? The problem is NP-complete by reduction to subset sum, but a straightforward greedy algorithm can achieve a solution at most twice the optimum.

Comment: I was hoping for an exact solution, but I guess an approximate algorithm will do. I'll look into the NP-C algorithm approximations to see if I can do better than the greedy approximation.

Comment: @user2357112 Is it reducible to subset sum? Here the sum is given to be zero, all you need is an optimal abs minimum running total.

Comment: To solve a [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) with input represented as a list `S`, solve this problem with input `S+[-sum(S)]` and see if the peak is `sum(S)/2`. If it is, `-sum(S)` splits the answer to this problem into two subsets that answer the partition problem. Otherwise, the answer to the partition problem is "no". That doesn't give an algorithm to answer *this* problem, but I suspect we can find a reduction similarly straightforward from this problem to another NP-complete problem.

Comment: Can you give an example with expected result ?

Comment: Vikram: see my edits.

Comment: How long of an array are we talking about? How large are the numbers inside?

Comment: The array is about 5 items right now for the small tests I'm doing, but I'd like to go way higher than that. The numbers are actually fixed-point precision, but that's equivalent to int if you multiply by some factor. I'd like to keep high precision, so the resulting ints will be large.

Comment: user2357112: that makes sense to me. Something to note for future readers: partition problem deals with positive numbers only, guaranteeing that SUM(S) >= ( any item  in S ).

Comment: what about my approach ? is it good or I am missing something ?

Comment: did it my way ... edited my question and add some code for testing ... do not forget to remove unused modes on the real thing ... also bubble sort is slow but easy to code so it will be fine to change it to quick sort or what ever

Answer (score 0):

this may be a bogus (if I misunderstood the problem) but sometimes the easiest way is the best one

- if the int's are unsigned then there is no help
- if there are signed then:

1.input array

- 1,5,-2,7,-6,4,-10,-3,...

2.separate signed and unsigned valueas and sort by value

- +1,+4,+5,+7,...
- -2,-3,-6,-10,...

3.reorder original array

- this can be done more ways
- the easiest one is just even numbers are + and odd ones are -
- +1,-2,+4,-3,+5,-6,+7,-10
- this is fast but not optimal
- still will cut down the peak significantly
- another option is:

  1.while (sum>=0) add number from +array

  2.while (sum< 0) add number from -array

  3.when one array is all used then copy the unused rest
- do not think you can do better then this

Where did the NP complete come from ???

- or I am missing something ???

[edit 1]

- also it can be improved to obtain optimal solution  like
- use smaller from the big unused values to get sum to half size of the max unused value from the opposite array...
- also all can be done in-place

[edit 2] some code and testing

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void min_sum_peak()
    {
    const int N=1000;
    int in[N],out[N];
    int i,s,sp,e,ip0,im0,ip1,im1;
    // generate sum=0 random array to in and clear out (for easyier debug)
    for (s=0,i=1;i<N;i++)
        {
        in[i]=Random(1000)-500;
        s+=in[i];
        out[i]=0;
        } in[0]=-s; out[0]=0;

    // bubble sort in[]
    for (e=1;e;)
    for (e=0,i=1;i<N;i++)
     if (in[i-1]>in[i])
      { e=in[i-1]; in[i-1]=in[i]; in[i]=e; e=1; }


    // fill out[]
    #define peak { e=s; if (e<0) e=-e; if (sp<e) sp=e; }
    for (int mode=0;mode<3;mode++)
        {
        // scann for +/- boundary
        im0=-1; ip0=N;
        im1= 0; ip1=N-1;
        for (i=0;i<N;i++)
         if (in[i]<0) im0=i;
          else { ip0=i; break; }

        if (mode==0)            // even odd from smaller values (sp = ~2*max)
         for (i=0,s=0,sp=0;i<N;)
            {
            if (im0>=im1){ out[i]=in[im0]; s+=out[i]; im0--; i++; peak; }
            if (ip0<=ip1){ out[i]=in[ip0]; s+=out[i]; ip0++; i++; peak; }
            }
        if (mode==1)            // even odd from bigger values (sp = ~max)
         for (i=0,s=0,sp=0;i<N;)
            {
            if (im0>=im1){ out[i]=in[im1]; s+=out[i]; im1++; i++; peak; }
            if (ip0<=ip1){ out[i]=in[ip1]; s+=out[i]; ip1--; i++; peak; }
            }
        if (mode==2)            // -half sum to next max value (sp = ~0.5*max for big enough array)
            {
            for (i=0,s=0,sp=0;;)
                {
                if (im0<im1) break; // stop if any + or - valueas are exhausted
                if (ip0>ip1) break;
                if (s>=0)
                    {
                    if (+s+s<-in[im1]){ out[i]=in[ip0]; s+=out[i]; ip0++; i++; }
                    else              { out[i]=in[im1]; s+=out[i]; im1++; i++; }
                    }
                else{
                    if (-s-s<+in[ip1]){ out[i]=in[im0]; s+=out[i]; im0--; i++; }
                    else              { out[i]=in[ip1]; s+=out[i]; ip1--; i++; }
                    }
                peak;
                }
            for (;im0>=im1;){ out[i]=in[im0]; s+=out[i]; im0--; i++; peak; }
            for (;ip0<=ip1;){ out[i]=in[ip0]; s+=out[i]; ip0++; i++; peak; }
            }
        i=-in[0]; if (i<in[N-1]) i=in[N-1];
        // breakpoint here for approach assesment
        mode=mode;  // used approach
        i = i;      // abs max value
        s = s;      // sum
        sp=sp;      // sum peak
        }
    #undef peak { e=s; if (e<0) e=-e; if (sp<e) sp=e; }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- mode 0 - even odd from smaller values sp = ~2*max_abs_value
- mode 1 - even odd from bigger values sp = ~max_abs_value
- mode 2     - half sum to next max value sp = ~0.5*max_abs_value
- for big enough arrays with 'evenly' distributed +/- values is mode 2 the best as expected
- but if array is small (for example N=20) then mode 1 is the winner
- mode 0 is not good at all